# netstat shows many times deploy.akamaitechnologies.com connected to my server

Tags: http, tcp, netstat

Many times, after running netstat on my server, I find one of IP addresses belonging to deploy.akamaitechnologies.com connected to my server, do someone has an idea on what is happening on my server ?

this is a case:

TCP    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49189    a184-25-107-184:http   ESTABLISHED

To what could serve the port: 49189  when the source machine is running http ?

Comment: Your question is based on the false assumption that they are connecting to you. If you look closely at the ports, you can see that it is almost certain that you are connecting to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is connecting to HTTP on the deploy.akamaitechnologies.com server, not the other way around. Run netstat -a -n -o on your server and see what PID (process ID) is responsible for the connection and investigate from there.

Answer (score 0):

that's a dynamic port that TCP needs to make a connection, if you really want to find out more look in your apache's log grep for that IP and see what this IP is doing, block it if you have too.

Comment: I am on IIS 7, how can I see what this IP is doing, and how can I block it please?

Comment: look in your IIS log what this IP is doing on your box so extensively to block it you can use IIS as well (or firewall)

Comment: Is there an iis log viewer / analyzer inside Windows 2008 R2, or have I to dowload it somewhere ? I can block the used IP address through the firewall but each time they use a different one, I mean: deploy.akamaitechnologies.com

Comment: Why would he look in his Apache log? It's the *local* port that's dynamic.

Comment: @David, So you think that something installed on my server connects  to them from time to time?

Comment: Yes. If you have the ability to log the HTTP headers, that would probably narrow it down.

Comment: Have you please an idea on how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you turn windows updates off and remove Adobe then deploy.akamaitechnologies.com is still be called using static ip-addresses that change each time and this happens during log on and before you have a chance to run something to block them

since you don't know all the ip-addresses then its not possible to block using windows firewall and you won't find the domain name or ip-address in the registry or even in any of the files on your c-drive so someone has gone to a great deal of trouble to connect you to one of akamai servers and you can bet they are upto no good

it's my machine, i will decide who and when i make a connection and what i want to block and not spy the master general at microsoft or anyone else for that matter.

current IP's used to bypass security are

213.120.161.155 Server: AkamaiGHost
213.120.161.186
80.150.133.34 
80.150.193.17
92.123.99.235

Sometime the host process is srvhost ran and ran "local" and other times it from another process ran as "system".

Answer (score 0):

This may be old news by now, but I ran into the same issue as Alpha Bird and Google was not very clarifying about Akamai Technologies - only that it is seemed pretty harmless judging by the information that is available online (e.g. Wikipedia and the company website).

Anyway, Joe Qwerty's reply above put me on the right track to solve the mystery on my  system, which is CentOS 6.6 by the way. On linux `netstat -a -n -o --tcp --program` demonstrated that the clock-applet was retrieving it's information from AKamai Technologies. Turning the clock in the task bar off made the http (port 80) connections go away. It also confirmed that it was pretty harmless, basically.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've discovered that Windows 8 now apparently automatically (i.e. without asking or without one going to the Windows app store) downloads the 8.1 service pack after installing some 8.0 updates.

This download seemed to come from a-{some-numbers-and-dashes}.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com and took up about 3GB + 0.5 to 0.7GB (2 parts), downloading at a rate of about 10Mb/sec on my ADSL2 connection.

If you see this huge a download, and you get a 8.1 auto-install-now-yes/no notification then it looks like this is it. Thus, maybe Microsoft is using this service also.